# After subraction of 4 neighbor pixels always give zero

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to take difference of center pixel with 4 neighbor and add them and then replace the original with that difference value. but it always replace pixel with zero. I don't what i am doing wrong. thanks for any help

```
// newproject.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "highgui.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>  // Gaussian Blur
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>        // Basic OpenCV structures (cv::Mat, Scalar)
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

class frameprocessing{

Mat hsv_base;
MatND hist_base;

public:
    void whatever(Mat Frame)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<Frame.cols;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<Frame.rows;j++)
            {
                if(i==0&&j==0)
                {

                //  cout<<"Check 1"<<endl;
                    Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i)=(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i)-(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j+1,i))+(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i)-Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i+1))+(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i)-Frame.at<Vec3b>(j+1,i))+(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i)-Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i+1)));

                    Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i)=(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i))[0]/4;
                    Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i)=(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i))[1]/4;
                    Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i)=(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i))[2]/4;

                }
                else if(i==Frame.cols-1&&j==Frame.rows-1)
                {
                //  cout<<"Check 2"<<endl;
                    Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i)=((Frame.at<Vec3b>(j-1,i)-Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i))+(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i-1)+Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i))+(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j-1,i)-Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i))+(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i-1)+Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i)));
                    Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i)=(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i))[0]/4;
                    Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i)=(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i))[1]/4;
                    Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i)=(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i))[2]/4;
                }
                else if(i==Frame.cols-1&&j==0)
                {
                                          //cout<<"Check 3"<<endl;
                    Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i)=((Frame.at<Vec3b>(j+1,i)-Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i))+(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i-1)+Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i))+(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j+1,i)-Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i))+(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i-1)+Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i)));
                    Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i)=(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i))[0]/4;
                    Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i)=(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i))[1]/4;
                    Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i)=(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i))[2]/4;
                }
                else if(i==0&&j==Frame.rows-1)
                {
                //  cout<<"Check 4"<<endl;
                    Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i)=((Frame.at<Vec3b>(j-1,i)-Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i))+(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i+1)+Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i))+(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j-1,i)-Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i))+(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i+1)+Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i)));
                    Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i)=(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i))[0]/4;
                    Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i)=(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i))[1]/4;
                    Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i)=(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i))[2]/4;
                }
                else if(i==0)
                {
            //      cout<<"Check 5"<<endl;
                    Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i)=((Frame.at<Vec3b>(j+1,i)-Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i))+(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i+1)-Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i))+(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i+1)-Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i))+((Frame.at<Vec3b>(j-1,i)-Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i))));
                    Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i)=(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i))[0]/4;
                    Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i)=(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i))[1]/4;
                    Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i)=(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i))[2]/4;

                }
                else if(j==0)
                {
            //      cout<<"Check 6"<<endl;
                    Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i)=((Frame.at<Vec3b>(j+1,i)-Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i))+(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j+1,i)-Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i))+(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i+1)-Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i)+(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i-1)-Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i))));
                    Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i)=(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i))[0]/4;
                    Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i)=(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i))[1]/4;
                    Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i)=(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i))[2]/4;
                }
                else if(i==Frame.cols-1)
                {
            //      cout<<"Check 7"<<endl;
                    Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i)=((Frame.at<Vec3b>(j+1,i)-Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i))+(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j-1,i)-Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i))+((Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i-1)-Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i)))+((Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i-1)-Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i))));
                    Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i)=(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i))[0]/4;
                    Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i)=(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i))[1]/4;
                    Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i)=(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i))[2]/4;

                }
                else if(j==Frame.rows-1)
                {
            //      cout<<"Check 8"<<endl;

                    Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i)=((Frame.at<Vec3b(j,i+1)-Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i))+(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j-1,i)-Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i))+(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j-1,i)-Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i))+((Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i-1)-Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i))));
                    Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i)=(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i))[0]/4;
                    Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i)=(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i))[1]/4;
                    Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i)=(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i))[2]/4;
                }
                else
                {

                    Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i)=((Frame.at<Vec3b>(j-1,i)-Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i))+(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j+1,i)-Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i))+(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i+1)-Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i))+(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i-1)+Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i)));
                    Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i)=(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i))[0]/4;
                    Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i)=(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i))[1]/4;
                    Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i)=(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i))[2]/4;
                    Vec3d value = Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i);
                    cout<<value[0]<<endl;
                    cout<<value[1]<<endl;
                    cout<<value[2]<<endl;
                }   
            }
            //hell(Frame);
    }
 };
 class video{   

    Mat frame;
    string filename;
    double dWidth;
    double dHeight;

public:
    video()
    {

    }

    video(string videoname)
    {
        vector<Mat> videoframes;
        filename = videoname;
        VideoCapture capture(filename); 

        if( !capture.isOpened() )
        {
            exit(0);
        }

        dWidth   = capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH); //get the width of frames of the video
        dHeight = capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT); //get the height of frames of the video
        frameprocessing obj;

        for( ; ; )
        {
            capture >> frame;
            if(frame.empty())
                break;

    //      Mat tmp=frame.clone();
            obj.whatever(frame);
    //      obj.hsv_histogram(frame);
    //      videoframes.push_back(tmp);
        }
        //displayvideo(videoframes);
        //writer(videoframes);
    }


};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    video obj("video.avi");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need Lapacian with kernel size parameter = 1, see here: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=laplacian#laplacian

You just need divide result by 4 after convolution for correct Laplacian.

As for your code, I think you should use different images as source and destination, you cant do this inplace.

```
class frameprocessing{

    Mat hsv_base;
    MatND hist_base;

public:
    void whatever(Mat Frame)
    {  
        Frame.convertTo(Frame,CV_32FC3);
        Mat newimage=Mat::zeros(Frame.size(),CV_32FC3);
        for (int j=1;j<Frame.rows-1;++j)
        {
            for (int i=1;i<Frame.cols-1;++i)
            {
                newimage.at<Vec3f>(j,i)=Frame.at<Vec3f>(j,i)-
                    0.25*Frame.at<Vec3f>(j+1,i)-
                    0.25*Frame.at<Vec3f>(j,i+1)-
                    0.25*Frame.at<Vec3f>(j-1,i)-
                    0.25*Frame.at<Vec3f>(j,i-1);
                    cout << newimage.at<Vec3f>(j,i) << endl;
            }
        }
        //imshow("result",newimage);
        //cv::waitKey(30);
    }
};
class video{   

    Mat frame;
    string filename;
    double dWidth;
    double dHeight;

public:
    video()
    {

    }

    video(string videoname)
    {
        vector<Mat> videoframes;
        filename = videoname;
        VideoCapture capture(filename); 

        if( !capture.isOpened() )
        {
            exit(0);
        }

        dWidth   = capture.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH); //get the width of frames of the video
        dHeight = capture.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT); //get the height of frames of the video
        frameprocessing obj;

        for( ; ; )
        {
            capture >> frame;
            if(frame.empty())
                break;

            //      Mat tmp=frame.clone();
            obj.whatever(frame);
            //      obj.hsv_histogram(frame);
            //      videoframes.push_back(tmp);


        }
        //displayvideo(videoframes);
        //writer(videoframes);
    }


};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    namedWindow("result");
    video obj("D:\\ImagesForTest\\atrium.avi");
}
```

Comment: i have tried to make newimage but it is not showing anything as a output

Comment: newimage.at<Vec3b>(j,i)=(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i)-(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j+1,i))+(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i)-Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i+1))+(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i)-Frame.at<Vec3b>(j+1,i))+(Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i)-Frame.at<Vec3b>(j,i+1)));

Comment: Vec3b value = newimage.at<Vec3b>(j,i);
      cout<<value[0]<<endl;
      cout<<value[1]<<endl;
      cout<<value[2]<<endl;

Comment: I've added code to my answer. I think that you should use float point values for computations. After convolution, you can convert result to any type you want, but remember that you get signed result, and some values are negative.

Comment: when i use vec3f or vec3d it got crashed . please help me

Comment: I've corrected my answer for your code. I tested it and it works fine.

Comment: thanks alot . i need one more favor i want to print this but simply using cout gives syntax error

Comment: I've added inside niternal loop (after newimage pixel value computation) cout << newimage.at<Vec3f>(j,i) << endl; and in prints me vectors.

Comment: i don't know why it is not working for me it gives me syntax error

Comment: I've added cout to my answer.